# Altera Cyclone IV memory block Verilog module

Tags: verilog, memory, intel-fpga, cyclone

[This document](http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/cyclone-iv/cyiv-51003.pdf) explains the various characteristics of the Altera Cyclone IV memory blocks (known as "M9K").

However, there is no mention as to how these modules should be instantiated in Verilog. Where can I find the M9K memory block Verilog module documentation? Does Altera provide example code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Recommended HDL Coding Styles](http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/qts/qts_qii51007.pdf) gives detail on how to instantiate various memory and other functions. It also mentions other useful documents. I assume you can also use a wizard to setup memory (megafunctions I think, though you probably know this already)